# Вызов default метода интерфейса из потомка, Java 8

Tags: java, ооп, java-8

Я хочу вызвать дефолтный метод из интерфейса, но компилятор это не пропускает.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    B b = new B();
    b.a();
 }
}

interface A{
    default void a() {
        System.out.println("Hi from A.a");
    }
}

class B implements A {
    @Override
    public void a() {
        super.a();   // Error
        System.out.println("Hi from B.a");
     }
}
```

Если это нельзя сделать, обьясните пожалуйста почему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**default** методы добавлены для обеспечения обратной совместимости с ранними версиями **Java**.

Используя их вы можете расширить уже существующий интерфейс не ломая код, который написан для предыдущей версии интерфейса. Все, что будет нужно - это перекомпилировать его. А так как в предыдущей версии этого метода не было, то вы не можете его вызвать используя **super**.

Вам нужно использовать абстрактный класс вместо интерфейса или не переопределять метод интереса.

**Абстрактный класс**

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        B b = new B();
        b.a();
    }
}

abstract class A {
    void a() {
        System.out.println("Hi from A.a");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void a() {
        super.a();
        System.out.println("Hi from B.a");
    }
}
```

**Интерфейс**

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        B b = new B();
        b.a();
    }
}

interface A{
    default void a() {
        System.out.println("Hi from A.a");
    }
}

class B implements A {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A.super.a();
```

Вот так можно вызвать